# How can I select the first representative element for each group of a DataFrameGroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My question is related with the selection of the **first most frequent** element for each group of a DataFrameGroupBy object. Specifically, I am having the following dataframe:

```
data = [
    [1000, 1, 1], [1000, 1, 1], [1000, 1, 1], [1000, 1, 2], [1000, 1, 2],
    [1000, 1, 2], [2000, 0, 1], [2000, 0, 1], [2000, 1, 2],
    [2000, 0, 2], [2000, 1, 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['route_id', 'direction_id', 'trip_id'])
```

Then, I group my `df` based on the columns `route_id`, `direction_id` by using:

```
t_groups = df.groupby(['route_id','direction_id'])
```

I would like to store the value of the `trip_id` column based on the **first most popular** `trip_id` of each unique `route_id`, `direction_id` combination.

Ι have tried to apply a function `value_counts()` but I cannot get the first popular `trip_id` value.

I would like my expected output to be like:

```
   route_id  direction_id  trip_id
0      1000             1        1
1      2000             0        1
2      2000             1        2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [GroupBy pandas DataFrame and select most common value](/q/15222754/4518341). TL;DR `t_groups['trip_id'].agg(pd.Series.mode)`

Comment: Whoops, actually, if there's more than one most common value, it'll return both but I thought it'd only return the first. So, `.agg(lambda s: s.mode()[0])`. (If you wanted both, you could do `.apply(pd.Series.mode)`.)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. It'd help to post the code you already tried, but apart from that, this is a great first question :)

Comment: Thank you very much @wjandrea. I will have this in mind for my next questions!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for.

```
df = df.groupby(['route_id', 'direction_id']).first().reset_index()
```

The `reset_index()` just moves your indices into columns looking exactly like the output you want.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP's looking for. It sounds like they're actually looking for the first *most frequent* value. Their example is ambiguous though.

Comment: That's right @wjandrea